# Why is codenameone REST giving me file name too long error?

Tags: codenameone

> ```
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/jamesagada/.cn1/cn1ConCache/aHR0cHM6Ly96aWVtb3ppLWEzZWYucmVzdGRiLmlvL3Jlc3QvemllbW96aS11c2Vycz9maWx0ZXI9JnE9JTdCJTIycGhvbmUlMjIlM0ElMjAlMjIwODAzNDAyMTI2OCUyMiUyMCUyQyUyMnBhc3N3b3JkJTIyJTNBJTIwJTIydHdhbGElMjIlMjAlN0QmbWV0YWZpZWxkcz10cnVlJm1heD0xMCZoPSU3QiUyMiUyNG9yZGVyYnklMjIlM0ElN0IlMjJfY3JlYXRlZCUyMiUzQSUyMC0xJTIwJTdEJTdEJnNraXA9MCZmZXRjaENoaWxkcmVuPXRydWU=
> ```
>
> (File name too long)  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
>     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)     at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:213)    at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:101)    at
>   com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.openFileOutputStream(JavaSEPort.java:8543)
>     at
>   com.codename1.io.FileSystemStorage.openOutputStream(FileSystemStorage.java:274)
>     at
>   com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.performOperation(ConnectionRequest.java:792)
>     at
>   com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.run(NetworkManager.java:282)
>     at
>   com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
>   [Network Thread] 0:0:19,345 - Exception: java.io.IOException - Stream
>   closed java.io.IOException: Stream closed     at
>   com.codename1.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:140)
>     at
>   com.codename1.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:338)
>     at
>   com.codename1.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:445)
>     at
>   com.codename1.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:668)
>     at com.codename1.io.Util.copyNoClose(Util.java:136)     at
>   com.codename1.io.Util.copyNoClose(Util.java:122)  at
>   com.codename1.io.Util.copy(Util.java:157)     at
>   com.codename1.io.Util.copy(Util.java:111)     at
>   com.codename1.io.Util.readInputStream(Util.java:206)  at
>   com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.readResponse(ConnectionRequest.java:1308)
>     at
>   com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.performOperation(ConnectionRequest.java:797)
>     at
>   com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.run(NetworkManager.java:282)
>     at
>   com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)

This is the error I am getting while using REST to access a URL. I cannot think of any reason why. I notice that this happens when some query parameters are specified but the server returns valid results.

Comment: That "long filename" is actually a base64-encoded string.  It decodes to this: `https://ziemozi-a3ef.restdb.io/rest/ziemozi-users?filter=&q=%7B%22phone%22%3A%20%2208034021268%22%20%2C%22password%22%3A%20%22twala%22%20%7D&metafields=true&max=10&h=%7B%22%24orderby%22%3A%7B%22_created%22%3A%20-1%20%7D%7D&skip=0&fetchChildren=true`.  The first embedded HTML-encoded string decodes to this: `{"phone": "08034021268" ,"password": "twala" }`.

Comment: yes. but why is the connection failing and giving me this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the default caching mode for `ConnectionRequest` is smart caching. So we try to save the content of the connection for later retrieval. This ignores the fact that windows FAT file system has limits on file length. This is fixed for the coming update and would limit the file name to 255 characters which should work. The update will also add the API `cacheMode(ConnectionRequest.CachingMode)` to the `RequestBuilder` class so you can customize the caching on an individual level.

As a workaround you can disable caching globally using:

```
ConnectionRequest.setDefaultCacheMode(ConnectionRequest.CachingMode.OFF);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just got the exact same issue and found out that ConnectionRequest raises an internal exception, that I can find only when testing within the simulator.
The URL that is passed to the request is base64 encoded, this is why it becomes a file name which is too long.
Setting the cache mode on each ConnectionRequest has no effect. So the only workaround is to use setDefaultCacheMode.
I hope to test the next release.